# Equivalent for @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) for JUnit5

Tags: java, junit, migration, junit4, junit5

In my project I'm doing some cleanup and decided to move everything to JUnit5.

Till this time, I was using

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
```

Now I want to migrate it to @ExtendWith. Is there any equivalent for this JUnitPlatform.class in JUnit5?

Comment: If you're wondering about `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` in JUnit5 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369022/should-springrunner-be-used-in-spring-boot-with-junit-5

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need it anymore when using junit 5.

In the [junit documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/platform/runner/JUnitPlatform.html) it states:

Annotating a class with @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) allows it to be run with IDEs and build systems that support JUnit 4 but do not yet support the JUnit Platform directly.

So since you are migrating to junit 5 I suppose your build system/IDE supports it. Hence, you don't need the annotation anymore.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have another fast question. CamelSpringBootRunner and CamelSpringRunner aren't migrated yet and I can't just simply delete it like JUnitPlatform?

Comment: You won't be able to migrate those to junit 5 then.

Comment: (until Camel decides to resolve this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11807)

Comment: so what would I do if I wanted to run an android project test with Robolectric? I usually would do `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)`

Answer (score 9):

Junit4 `@RunWith` has been replaced by `@ExtendWith` in JUnit5 as of content from https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith