# @RunWith not compiling in JUnit5

Tags: java, junit, runner

My project is set up with JUnit 5, and I want to use a different Runner for my tests, but I can't even use the @RunWith annotation because it won't compile. In this guide, https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-runwith, it says that RunWith should still work in JUnit 5, so I'm confused why it won't even compile.
Even https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dependency-injection has an example of using RunWith if you scroll down a bit:
`Using @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) will output all reported entries to stdout.`
So why won't my code compile? Have I misunderstood something?

running gradlew build:

```
TestGameController.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
@RunWith(CacioTestRunner.class)
 ^
  symbol: class RunWith
```

Comment: RunWith is a JUnit 4 annotation. See its package: `org.junit.runner.RunWith`. There is no "jupiter" in the package. The "equivalent" in JUnit 5 is ExtendWith, which expects a JUnit 5 extension class as argument. You'll need to add a dependency on JUnit 4, write the test with the JUnit 4 API, and use the vintage engine of JUnit 4 if there is no CacioExtension class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent for @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) for JUnit5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462395/equivalent-for-runwithjunitplatform-class-for-junit5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JB Nizet answered my question in his comment.

> RunWith is a JUnit 4 annotation. See its package:
> org.junit.runner.RunWith. There is no "jupiter" in the package. The
> "equivalent" in JUnit 5 is ExtendWith, which expects a JUnit 5
> extension class as argument. You'll need to add a dependency on JUnit
> 4, write the test with the JUnit 4 API, and use the vintage engine of
> JUnit 4 if there is no CacioExtension class.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue which gets resolved by **adding** the
**@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)** annotation before **@RunWith** annotation.

Comment: Adding `@ExtendsWith` won't do anything to address the fact that `@RunWith` doesn't exist in Junit 5.

Comment: Completely agree @MassDotNet, But in case someone needs work around it may help to compile their code.