# Should SpringRunner be used in Spring Boot with Junit 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am confused about the class SpringRunner.
From Stackoverflow and google did understand that `SpringRunner` and `SpringJunit4ClassRunner` are one and the same.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

My understanding of this class is :

- that as its name implies - it is a 'runner' ( it will run the Junit tests )
- This class is used while performing unit testing with the annotation `@RunWith`
- This annotation helps in loading a spring application context and helps ‘autowire’ dependencies.
- This class should only be used if we need spring context bean dependencies.
- So this class should be used with caution otherwise we will unnecessarily load spring context during testing.
- This class helps Junit and Spring collaborate together.

With Junit5 and spring boot is this class no longer required ?

If yes what should we be using in a spring boot and Junit5 environment then ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the reference [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)

> If you are using JUnit 4, don’t forget to also add
>   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) to your test, otherwise the annotations
>   will be ignored. If you are using JUnit 5, there’s no need to add the
>   equivalent @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) as @SpringBootTest and
>   the other @…Test annotations are already annotated with it.

Answer (score 8):

> With Junit5 and spring boot is this class no longer required?

The annotation `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` is no longer required, you can delete it.

Additionally, if you use only Junit5, it is recommended to exclude Junit4:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

`@RunWith` is a JUnit4 API.

In JUnit 5, use `@ExtendedWith` instead. Spring core provides a new SpringExtension for it.
And there are some more flexible annotation available, eg. `SpringJunitConfig`

```java
@SpringJunitConfig(classes= config classes)
public class ASpringTest
{}
```

For the usage of SpringJunitConfig, check more examples from [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/database-client/src/test/java/com/example/demo).

In the latest Spring Boot 2.4, JUnit 5 is the default test runner, use `@SpringBootTest` is enough, and Spring Boot also provide test slice capabilities for Spring Data, check my example [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/boot/src/test/java/com/example/demo).

Comment: note: it's `SpringJUnitConfig` (capital U) from package `org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter`