# How to write a test suite with junit 5 for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tdd, junit5, test-suite

I am trying to run by junit5 tests from a test suite. however Im getting an error

```
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.test.studentservice.controllers.StudentControllerTest2;
import com.test.studentservice.repo.StudentServiceRepoDataTest;
import com.test.studentservice.service.StudentServiceTest;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses({StudentControllerTest2.class, StudentServiceRepoDataTest.class, StudentServiceTest.class})
public class StudentServiceTestSuite {

}
```

This is the error I'm getting:
[image: this is the error im getting]

Thanks

Comment: A common mistake in JUnit5 is to tag the test methods with `org.junit.Test` instead of `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`. You can right-click a package and choose _Run As > JUnit Test_, so you don't need to write code to list all test classes of a package. If this does not help, tell whether you can run a class as JUnit test and show a minimal example containing also the code of the test class.

Comment: @howlger Thanks, right-clicking on the package and running the jUnit test is working fine. however I need to have a test suite as per the requirement.  i have re-checked and im using `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` for every test.  im following https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5 test suite example

Answer (score 1):

You get this error, because **in the JUnit launch configuration** (*Run > Run Configurations...*) in the *Test* tab, you selected as ***Test runner*** the option ***JUnit 5* instead of *JUnit 4***.

**`@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`** is used for the purpose **to run JUnit 5 tests as JUnit 4 tests**, in case a tool only supports JUnit 4 but not JUnit 5 ([for details see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57462634/6505250)). But you don't need that since Eclipse supports JUnit 5 and should not use it since running it via the JUnit 4 API has some limitations.

[Baeldung - A Guide to JUnit 5 - 7. Test Suites](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5#test-suites) which [you mentioned in a comment you are following here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022322/how-to-write-a-test-suite-with-junit-5-for-eclipse?noredirect=1#comment116738003_66022322), is wrong, or at least misleading in this point. Instead of a JUnit  Test Suite class, tag your tests and use them to include or to exclude tests (in the JUnit launch configuration, in the *Test* tab, hit the *Configure...* button for that).

Answer (score 1):

From October-November 2021 jUnit5 **support @Suite** annotation:

```
    import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
    import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
    import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SuiteDisplayName;

    @Suite
    @SuiteDisplayName("Build Verification Test")
    // Insert the class names in the order of execution
    @SelectClasses({
            FirstTest.class,
            SecondTest.class
    })
    public class SuiteTest {
        
    }
```

Pom:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.8.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.8.0</junit.platform.version>
</properties>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
```